# How to place 2 cards per row with flex

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'll provide images of what I'm trying to perform:

One that is how I want it to be and one that shows the problem, finally I'll show the code.

First image (how I want it to be):

[image: What I want]

Second image (how it looks when I have a third card)

[image: The problem]

Here is the code:

```
<ScrollView>
    <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
        <View style={{ paddingTop: '5%' }}></View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>

            {this.state.subjects.map(subject => {
                return (
                    <View key={subject.id}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewSubject', { id: subject.id })}>
                            <ImagedCarouselCard
                                width={180}
                                height={180}
                                text={subject.name}
                                shadowColor="#051934"
                                source={{
                                    uri: "http://site.test/" + subject.icon,
                                }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                )
            })}
        </View>
        <View style={{ paddingTop: '2%' }}></View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set `flexWrap` to `wrap` in Container style
2. Set `width` of each cards to `(screen width - card margin * 3) / 2`

This is my functional component example

**But using FlatList and set `numColumns` to 2 is more useful**
[FlatList numColumn](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns)

[image]

```
const subjects = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Card 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Card 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Card 3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Card 4' },
  ];

  const cardGap = 16;

  const cardWidth = (Dimensions.get('window').width - cardGap * 3) / 2;

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        {subjects.map((subject, i) => {
          return (
            <View
              key={subject.id}
              style={{
                marginTop: cardGap,
                marginLeft: i % 2 !== 0 ? cardGap : 0,
                width: cardWidth,
                height: 180,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                borderRadius: 16,
                shadowOpacity: 0.2,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{subject.name}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
```

You can see `flexWrap` [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex-wrap)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, just added the `flexWrap` but, apparently the third card is not touching the one right on top of it. Maybe that's why you added `screen width - card margin * 3` ? But, how would it be in actual code? I'm a bit confused. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @DanielLogvin I put actual snippet again

Comment: @DanielLogvin Wait, I will put my example soon

Comment: And where's `cardGap` defined? I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @DanielLogvin How about now?
I created `cardGap` variable for distance between card and side screens
`cardWidth` is calculated with screen width and `cardGap`

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer suggested by `@MJ Studio` but it did not work out for me, so I tried a work around, I know this is not an ideal solution, but it works for me, hope this is useful to someone else as well.

```
const renderComponents = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.cardwrap}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>Hello 1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>Hello 2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>Hello 3</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>Hello 4</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>Hello 5</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default renderComponents;

// . . . . . . . . . Styles . . . . . . . . .

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardwrap: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 30,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },

  card: {
    width: '45%',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingVertical: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

In the above mentioned code, I used `flexDirection: 'row'` to make sure that the cards are sequential and `flexWrap: 'wrap'` to contain the cards within the view.

Note : Make sure that the card designed is with width which does not span more that `50%` or else it would move to the next row.

[Sample image of the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HxSE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Flatlist **numColumn ={2}** you can follow my snippets.

```
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      contentContainerStyle={{alignItems:'center'}}
      columnWrapperStyle={{ flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
      numColumns={2}
      renderItem={({item}) => renderItem(item)}
    />
```